# Does fabric CA server have to be run in 24hours?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am wondering if Fabric CA server must be run in 24hours. If so, do I need any server computer(cloud or physical)?

Is there no other way to resolve authentication issue **by nodes autonomously without server cost**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The CA is only for users and nodes to be created. But once you have an certificate from the CA, you don't need it in order to transact on the Blockchain.

However, if you want to revoke a user/node you will need the CA to create a CRL.